# MySQL how to chain a single query across multiple tables to retrieve data?

Tags: mysql

I have been struggling with this query for awhile and I am not sure exactly how to accomplish this task: "Update Jarrod's Salary if his Deparment has at least 2 minions whose yearly review is over 1.0." We have the following tables:

```
Table Person {
    Name: Johnathan;  
    SSN: 1234;  


    Name: Robert;  
    SSN: 1324;  


    Name: Jarrod;
    SSN: 4231;

  }

  Table Overlord {

     OverlordID: 1234;
     Salary: 1000;

     OverlordID: 1324;
     Salary: 1330;

     OverlordID: 4231;
     Salary: 1210;

   }

  Table Minion {

    Name: Shemp;  
    SSN: 1264;  
    Yearly Review: 1.2;

    Name: Moe;  
    SSN: 1624;  
    Yearly Review: 0.2;

    Name: Curly;
    SSN: 4261;
    Yearly Review: 1.4;

  }

 Table Dept {

    DeptName: Evil;
    Sector: 1A;
    OverlordID: 1234;

    DeptName: Good;
    Sector: 2B;
    OverlordID: 4231;

  }

  Table Payrolls {

     DeptName: Good;
     Sector: 2B;
     MinionID: 1264;

     DeptName: Good;
     Sector: 2B;
     MinionID: 4261;

     DeptName: Evil;
     Sector: 1A;
     MinionID: 1624;

    }
```

I apologize for this being a complicated database structure, but using a structure like this, I need to know how it would be possible to:

Update Jarrod's Salary if his Deparment has at least 2 minions whose yearly review is over 1.0.

Comment: Real talk, is this a class assignment? If it's not, it sure looks like one.

Comment: What about providing sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use subqueries, like so:

```
SELECT MinionID FROM Payrolls WHERE DeptName = (
    SELECT DeptName FROM Dept WHERE OverlordID = (
        SELECT SSN FROM Person WHERE Name = "Jarrod"
    )
)
```

Basically we get the SSN for the person named Jarrod, then we get the department name headed by that SSN, then we get the minions who work for a department by that name.

That will return the following data:

```
MinionID
---------
1264
4261
```

You can then nest the above query within another query to join the MinionID with the Minion table:

```
SELECT * FROM Minion a JOIN (query from above) b ON (a.SSN = b.MinionID)
```

Or you can use the IN condition, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM Minion WHERE SSN IN (query from above)
```

At which point we can nest that within another query to get the count for how many rows satisfy YearlyReview > 1.0:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (query from above) c WHERE c.YearlyReview > 1.0;
```

That returns a table with a single row:

```
COUNT(*)
--------
2
```

So now you can nest *that* query within your if statement to see if the value was >= 2.

Here's what it looks like when you put all of the pieces together:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Minion WHERE SSN IN (
        SELECT MinionID FROM Payrolls WHERE DeptName = (
            SELECT DeptName FROM Dept WHERE OverlordID = (
                SELECT SSN FROM Person WHERE Name = "Jarrod"
            )
        )
    )
) c WHERE c.YearlyReview > 1.0;
```